# How do I import products into magento through csv to multiple stores at once

Tags: magento

I tried to put this is the store column  "admin, cabinetshops, floorsanding"   but it will skip the row every time now

Comment: You may want to provide some more information, as your question is very vague.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a product in admin interface
- assign to all the stores
- export the product using export product data flow project
- Examine the csv file and see what is it doing
- Format your csv same as your exported csv file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know free extensions that can perform this task. But in Magento Store Manager there is Multi Store Management feature. So you can simply switch between stores and import from .csv files to each store separately, but in one interface.

All you have to do is to press the Quick Connection Switch button in the Settings tab and pick the store you want. You can also click on Preferences button in the Settings tab or select it in the main menu to get an easy access to your Magento multiple stores databases. There’s also opportunity for you in the Preferences window to set either direct connection to your database or direct connection through HTTP tunnel or use PHP-MySQL bridge connection.